# AWS Website Hosting Free Tier Does Not Working?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, web, amazon-ec2, hosting

I'm currently using AWS services for my personal wordpress website hosting. But only three weeks,about $10 bill occured. I tried to taking help from AWS support center, but they did not answer. [Here's the bill details. The thing that I could not figure out, while I am using free monthly tier, how can I used on-demand instance type?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj4s6.png) I would be appreciate for any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your usage exceeds the monthly free tier limits, you simply pay standard, pay-as-you-go AWS service rates.

When an account goes over the free tier limit, the standard AWS service rates will be billed to your credit card.

If your application use exceeds the free tier limits, you simply pay standard, pay-as-you-go service rates –

To know you if I’ve gone over the free usage tiers- follow the following steps

You can see current and past usage activity by service and region by logging into your account and going to the Billing & Cost Management Dashboard. From there you can manage your costs and usage using AWS Budgets, visualize your cost drivers and usage trends via Cost Explorer, and dive deeper into your costs using the Cost and Usage Reports.

Answer (score 0):

On-Demand instances let you pay for compute capacity by the hour or second (minimum of 60 seconds) with no long-term commitments. This frees you from the costs and complexities of planning, purchasing, and maintaining hardware and transforms what are commonly large fixed costs into much smaller variable costs.

[On-Demand Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/)

Comment: I know that, but they give 750 hours per month and this free usage still did not over. This is the part I don't understand.

Comment: If your application use exceeds the free tier limits, you simply pay standard, pay-as-you-go service rates